# How to create a: toggle spreadMode button and one for enable Scrolling, on PDF.js, in aspnet.core?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

**Explanation**

I am building a custom page to read pdf books.

Following the example on `https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/` i was able to show the pdf files, zoom-in and zoom-out.
The problem i am having is not beeing able to call the functions of `<script src="../lib/pdf.js/viewer.mjs" type="module"></script>` to enable spreadMode on load and toggle it with a button, if neccessary. The same goes for the scrolling.

More precisely:

1. toggle the spreadMode
2. select the scrolling

**Question**

How can this be achieved?

**The full page code**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/pdf.js/pdf_viewer.css">
    <script src="../lib/pdf.js/pdf.mjs" type="module"></script>
    <script src="../lib/pdf.js/viewer.mjs" type="module"></script>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="text-center">

            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" id="zoominbutton" type="button">&nabla; ---</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" id="zoomoutbutton" type="button">&Delta; +++</button>

        </div>

        @* <p>&ensp;</p> *@
        <hr />
        
        <canvas class="text-center" id="the-canvas" ></canvas>

</body>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }

    <script>

        workerSrc = '../lib/pdf.js/pdf.worker.mjs';
        // window.PDFViewerApplication.baseUrl = window.ASSET_URL;
        window.GlobalWorkerOptions = workerSrc;
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
        // header on that server.
        // var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';
        var url = '../mypdfs/65894dce05dd1.pdf';
        var myscale = 1.0;

        // Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
        var { pdfjsLib } = globalThis;

        // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
        // pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.mjs';
        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = workerSrc;

        var pdfDoc = null,
            pageNum = 1,
            spreadModeOnLoad = 1,
            pageRendering = false,
            pageNumPending = null,
            scale = 0.5,
            canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       

        function renderPage(num) {

            pageRendering = true;
            var PRINT_RESOLUTION = 300;
            var PRINT_UNITS = PRINT_RESOLUTION / 150.0;

            // Using promise to fetch the page
            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function (page) {
                var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 5.11 });
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width + myscale;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: ctx,
                    viewport: viewport,
                };
                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

                // Wait for rendering to finish
                renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                    pageRendering = false;
                    if (pageNumPending !== null) {
                        // New page rendering is pending
                        renderPage(pageNumPending);
                        pageNumPending = null;
                    }
                });
            });

            // Update page counters
            document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
        }

        /**
         * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
         * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
         */
        function queueRenderPage(num) {
            if (pageRendering) {
                pageNumPending = num;
            } else {
                renderPage(num);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Displays previous page.
         */
        function onPrevPage() {
            if (pageNum <= 1) {
                return;
            }
            pageNum--;
            queueRenderPage(pageNum);
        }
        document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

        /**
         * Displays next page.
         */
        function onNextPage() {
            if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
                return;
            }
            pageNum++;
            queueRenderPage(pageNum);
        }
        document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

        var zoominbutton = document.getElementById("zoominbutton");
        zoominbutton.onclick = function () {
            myscale = myscale + 500;
            renderPage(pageNum);
        }

        var zoomoutbutton = document.getElementById("zoomoutbutton");
        zoomoutbutton.onclick = function () {
            if (myscale <= 500) {
                return;
            }
            myscale = myscale - 500;
            renderPage(pageNum);
        }

        /**
         * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
         */
        pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function (pdfDoc_) {
            pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
            document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

            // Initial/first page rendering
            renderPage(pageNum);
        });
    </script>

}
```